# My installation is stuck For a lot of time

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, software-installation

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop
I used erase everything and install Ubuntu
Configuration :
Ram : 8gb
No graphic card
Core i5 3 rd generation
It has been running some commands for the past 8 hrs but no change in progress bar

Comment: There's not really any actionable information here that might help describe the problem. Edit your question and include more details.

Comment: Hard to understand what your problem is! Please edit the question so that it is possible to understand your problem.